# como borrar la linea del pdf

Tags: php, pdf, fpdf, tcpdf

Al generar el archivo PDF, se ve así:

[image: contenido de una función para agregar firma digital al pdf]

Líneas que no deben estar ahí
[image: imagen del pdf lineas que no deben de estar ahí]

El código que uso es

```
  $config['file_name']        = $nombre_pdf;
              $config['upload_path']      = './pdf_generados/';
              $config['allowed_types']    = 'pdf';
              $config['max_size']         = 4096;
              $this->load->library('upload', $config);
              $route='';
              $this->upload->do_upload('pdf');
                  $pdf = new FPDI;
                  $page_count = $pdf->setSourceFile( ('pdf_generados/'.$nombre_pdf) );
                  for($i = 1; $i <= $page_count; $i++){
                      $tplidx = $pdf->importPage($i, '/MediaBox');
                      $size = $pdf->getTemplateSize($tplidx);
                      $pdf->AddPage();
                      $pdf->useTemplate($tplidx, null, null, $size['width'],$size['height'],true);
                  }
                  $titulo = $nombre_pdf;
                  $certificate = 'file://'.realpath( ('firma/firmalegal.crt') );
                  $info = array(
                      'Name' => $titulo
                  );
                  $route = FCPATH.'pdf_firmados/'.$nombre_pdf;
                  $pdf->setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'firma_Digital', '', 2, $info);
                  $pdf->setProtection($permissions=array('print','copy'));
                  $pdf->Output($route, 'F');
```

Comment: y cómo estás generando el PDF? Edita tu pregunta, por favor, y añade el código relevante

Comment: el problema es que genero el pdf normal...solo que al momento de llamar a ese pdf para firmar se agrega esa linea que no debe estar ahi